# slickgrid scroll jump back to top row

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

When I try to scroll, while scrolling, the grid resets the top row to first row.  It refuses to let me scroll down at all, it just jumps back to first row.  I've included the code below and sure would appreciate if someone could point out why.

```
function setGrid(d){
    var grid;
    var data = d;
    var columns = [
        { id : "questiontext", name: "Question", field : "QuestionText", sortable:true, behavior:"select", cssClass: "cell-selection", width:620, cannotTriggerInsert:true, formatter: formatgridInActiveDel},
        { id : "isactive", name: "Active", field : "IsActive", sortable:false, behavior:"select", cssClass: "cell-selection", width: 55, cannotTriggerInsert:true, formatter: chkboxFormatter},
        { id : "multianswer", name: "Multi Answer", field : "MultiAnswer", sortable:false, behavior:"select", cssClass: "cell-selection", width: 100, cannotTriggerInsert:true, formatter: chkboxFormatter},
        { id : "orderorq", name: "Order", field : "OrderOfQ", sortable:true, behavior:"select", cssClass: "cell-selection", width: 55, cannotTriggerInsert:true, formatter: formatgridcentercol},
        { id : "btnedit", name: "Edit", field : "Edit", sortable:false, behavior:"select", cssClass: "cell-selection", width: 55, cannotTriggerInsert:true, formatter: buttonFormatter},
        { id : "btndel", name :"Del", field: "Del", sortable:false, behavior:"select", cssClass: "cell-selection", width: 55, cannotTriggerInsert:true, formatter: buttonFormatter}
    ];
    var options = {
        enableCellNavigation: true,
        forceFitcolumns: true,
        multiSelect: false,
        syncColumnCellResize: true
    };
    dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
    grid = new Slick.Grid("#questiongrid", dataView, columns, options);
    var pager = Slick.Controls.Pager(dataView, grid, $("#questionpager"));

    grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel());
    grid.onClick.subscribe(function (e, args){
        e.stopPropagation();
        var cell = grid.getCellFromEvent(e);
        var col = grid.getColumns()[cell.cell];
        var item = dataView.getItem(args.row)

        EditDelQuestion(item, col.field)
    });
    dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function(e, args){
        grid.invalidateRows(args.rows);
        grid.render();
    });
    grid.onSort.subscribe(function (e, args) {
        slickGridSort(args.sortCol.field, args.sortAsc, grid, dataView);
    });
    dataView.beginUpdate();
    dataView.setPagingOptions({ pageSize: 12 });
    dataView.setItems(data, "TestQGridid");
    dataView.endUpdate();

}
```

Comment: is there any errors showing up in Firebug?

Comment: It doesn't scroll at all in Firefox or Chrome.  The IE console shows no errors

Comment: The IE console is very cheap of what help it can provide you, I strongly suggest you to install the Firebug extension for Firefox and then see if any JS errors comes up. Here's the link for the extension https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: Getting it now.  I had v27 which Firebug didn't work with.  Thx for the boost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a subscription

```
dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
  grid.updateRowCount();
  grid.render();
});
```

Comment: No, that didn't fix it.  Its crazy the way it behaves.  When I start trying to scroll, it scrolls down a line or two then, while I'm holding the scroll button down, it jumps back to the first line and repeats.  Think of a ball bouncing real fast.  That's the way it looks and acts.

Comment: I have seen this behavior before, but can't recall the different aspects that may cause it. Can you see if you can reproduce the issue in a fiddle. It doesn't seem to be an issue [using a generalization of the source provided](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/k29qauj6/)

Comment: Apparently the first time I tried your solution, the cache the local IIS server was messing me up.  I restarted my machine, tried your solution and it works on IE, Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera.  Thanks